# Compare Number from local file and overwrite if the number is higher than the local one

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I am Trying to compare an number from local file with an number that i'm scraping.
My unique problem is that I don't know how to read the file and compare it with the number I have. Everythin else works fine.

My code:

```
all_div = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='im_message_outer_wrap hasselect']")
for x in range(0,len(all_div)):
    idMessage = all_div[x].get_attribute('data-msg-id')
    if idMessage > open('idMessage.js', 'r'):
        all_div[x].click()
        fp = open('idMessage.js', 'w')
        fp.writelines(idMessage)
```

The error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'
```

The content inside the json file:

```
207
```

Note: 
The number inside the json file always change when something is bigger than him by the FOR loop.
The file it's a json one, but I can replace it for a .txt or any other extension without problem if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this for reading the js file.

```
# first read data from the js file
f = open('idMessage.js', 'r')
p = f.readline()
f.close()

all_div = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='im_message_outer_wrap hasselect']")
for x in range(0,len(all_div)):
    idMessage = all_div[x].get_attribute('data-msg-id')

    # use data from js file here
    if int(idMessage) > int(p.strip()):      
        all_div[x].click()
        fp = open('idMessage.js', 'w')
        fp.writelines(idMessage)
```